# How to loop id from url parameter

Tags: php, laravel

This is my request:

https://localhost/profiles?id=1,2

i want to have an output of this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$data = explode(',',  $_GET['id']);
$data =array_map(function($item){
    return ['id' => $item];
},$data);
echo json_encode(['data' => $data]);
```

https://eval.in/896004

Comment: I didn't recognize it was json, its too early for me +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
$data = array('data' => array());
foreach(explode(',', $_GET['id']) as $key => $val){
    $data['data'][$key]['id'] = $val;
}
print_r(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Just a good old explode and a foreach. Easy to read and understand. I'd probably had done `$data['data'][] = ['id' => $val];` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in more laravel way as well for more cleaner solution.

```
$data = explode(',',  $request->input('id'));

$data = collect($data)->map(function($item){
    return ['id' => $item];
});

dd(json_encode(['data' => $data]));
```

Comment: Oh this is awesome. How i missed to see Laravel there.+1

Comment: Rafraf dela Cruz if you are using Larvel really, try this code. And if this code worked for you then mark this answer as accepted. (only in the case if you are using laravel and given code working fine for you)

Comment: A fine example of how Laravel pointlessly reinvents the wheel. You can do this easily with plain old PHP and it would be more readable and portable and likely also faster.

Comment: Yes I am using laravel. This is great.

Comment: @Gordon I do accept that plain PHP code will be faster but I think it's not readable. And  PHP array functions have a lot of inconsistency in syntax. Like in array_reduce you need to first pass an array and in array_map first, you need to pass a callback. For this code snippet using collection doesn't do any magic but when it comes to complex array transformations collection can do wonders using method chaining and all other goodies.

Comment: @Suraj I am fine with agree to disagree. It's a working solution for sure, but there is no point in doing this "the Laravel way". It doesn't yield any benefit over just using plain old PHP.

Comment: @GordonYes partially, I agree with you. But personally, I like to keep uniform syntax and functions which can be modified or extend easily in future.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular simple case, you can also do with with  `preg_replace`:

```
printf('{"data":[%s]}', preg_replace('~(\d+)~', '{"id"=$1}', $_GET['id']));
```